# IE11 Polymer dom-module already defined

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

On IE11 i get:

```
A custom element with name 'dom-module' has already been defined.
```

On Chrome, Edge, etc its perfectly fine. Any idea?

My gulp looks like this:

```
const sourcesStream = mergeStream(project.sources(), project.dependencies())
    .pipe(sourcesHtmlSplitter.split())
    .pipe(gulpif(/\.js$/, babel({
        presets: ["env", {
            "targets": {
                "chrome": 52,
                "browsers": ["ie 11"]
            }]
    })))
    .pipe(gulpif(/\.js$/, uglify({
        compress: {
            drop_console: true
        }
    })))
    .pipe(gulpif(/\.(png|gif|jpg|svg)$/, imagemin()))
    .pipe(sourcesHtmlSplitter.rejoin())
gulp.task('debug', function() {
    return sourcesStream
        .pipe(project.bundler({
            sourcemaps: false,
            inlineCss: true,
            inlineScripts: true,
            stripComments: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDirectory));
});
```

dependencies versions:

```
"polymer-build": "2.1.0",
"polymer-bundler": "3.1.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of webcomponents you have? Seems v1.0.4 fix the error. See [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4739#issuecomment-318414964) (although the issue is still open).

Also, what other packages are you using? The problem could come from one of this packages. [Here](https://github.com/first87/polymer-chat/issues/26#issuecomment-318845515) the issue comes from zone.js.